# SpringSecurity page authentication not working properly

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-3

> I am new To Spring Security ,I use SpringBoot3 . I want when I hit
> localhost:8080/user it open my home page but in my case when I hit
> localhost:8080/user this url in my browser it redirect to my login
> page. I want every body access home page without any authentication ,
> How can I do this . I tried this way  for your better understand I
> submit my code for your reference.
>
> SecurityConfig.java

```
package io.nilmani.management.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/**")
                        .authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")  // Specify your custom login page URL
                        .permitAll()  // Allow everyone to access the login page
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
}
```

> UserEntityController.ja@Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserEntityController {
    @Autowired
    private UserEntityServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping
    public String homePage(){
        return "homePage";
    }
}
```

> LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping
    public String loginPage(){
        return "LoginPage";
    }
}
```

> My Requirement is when I hit localhost:8080/user it open my home page
> not login page.

Comment: what do you think `.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()` does

Answer (score 0):

requestMatchers("/user").permitAll()